# wcf request to client

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm looking for some suggestions to check if this is possible.
I'm writing a wcf service which allows the client to upload files.
I want to add a validation layer into my web service without the client having to upload the file.
So the client makes a request to wcf service with the file, but before it uploads I want to validate the file name and then possibly make a request to the client to send the file.
I could have 2 interfaces on my webservice: `validatefile()` and `uploadfile()` and the result from the `validationfile()` but ideally i would like to do it via a single interface.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: the validation is done to check the file size and filename. because the file might be 600mb, ideally i need to perform the check before the file is uploaded but within the service.

Comment: That's a fairly broad requirement.  Beyond the file name, what would you be "validating?"  What do you want to return to the client (from uploadfile()- presuming you only use one method) if the file isn't valid?

Comment: What do you plan on validating? The service can't access the file yet to even determine if the file even exists.

Comment: well in basic terms, we just want to validate the file name for x.  doesnt matter what the validation does.  but i just wanted to perform a validation method without uploading the file and without the user sending another request to the service.  if this isnt possible.. i'm happy to do the response and if a key is return then perform the file upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need separate interfaces unless you want to. It would be perfectly acceptable to have both the Validate and Upload methods in the same interface.

Beyond that, if you want to force a consumer to first call validate, then you could return a Guid "key" from the Validate method, and then have the consumer pass this key into the upload method. No upload key, no upload. Even with this approach, you will want to re-validate in the upload.

So your validate method could look something like this:

```
public string Validate(string fileName)
{
    string uploadKey = null;
    bool isValid = false;

    //Business logic

    if (isValid)
    {
        uploadKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //store uploadKey
    }

    return uploadKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole doesn't make sense. You can validate the file name and file size in the first request and the client can send another one after that. That would require you to make the hash from the file name and the size and keep the hash on the server. In the next request you would need to validate the hash = compute the hash again which goes to decision: Why to validate these values in a separate request if you have to do it again in the main request? If you don't do it your whole design is fragile and useless.

My approach would be:

Use only upload method. Place file name and file size as SOAP header and use streaming (you will probably use it anyway). Streaming allows you reading SOAP headers before you start processing (and loading) the stream so you can validate them and throw exception back to the client without loading the file.